# localhost/phpMyAdmin/ blank page on Windows 8

Tags: phpmyadmin, installation

Note:  I have Googled and read through all the topics here on Stackoverflow regarding this issue,
but none seem to match with what I'm experiencing.

I've set up a local server environment with the latest versions of Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Windows 8.

Everything works perfectly.

Now I've downloaded phpMyAdmin, and began to follow the [Windows install instructions](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html).

The problem is I can't get to any of the phpMyAdmin pages to install it.  Everything is a blank page.

Any variation of the localhost path to phpMyAdmin returns a blank page.

Any useful advice would be much appreciated. My apologies if I've broken any rules or haven't posted
exactly how I should have, so be gentle. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Is your phpmyadmin deployed on a path Apache is providing? I'd say first start by being able to view a simple php page from where your phpmyadmin source are locatade

Comment: What's confusing me is (I'm rebuilding the environment from scratch on a new Win8.1 laptop)... to test I copied the entire phpMyAdmin folder from the old machine, and pasted it into htdocs on the new one.  It worked fine! So all paths and whatever are set up correctly.  Also, php pages do display as well.  I just can't get the new phpMyAdmin to work.

Comment: the paths aren't contained in phpmyadmin, they are in apache config

Comment: Yes. And the fact that the older phpMyAdmin version works fine, means that the Apache config is correct. It ALL works perfectly on the Win7 machine. And everything works perfectly on the Win8 machine -- except phpMyAdmin.  The only difference is it's a newer version (4.2.9.1).

Comment: Have you copied the apache config from win7 to win8? Did the old phpmyadmin version work fine on the new server?

Comment: The old version worked fine on the new server, yes.  As for Win7's Apache config, no, but that's a good point. I'll test and post back.

Comment: Win7's apache config doesn't work in the new environment, either. But the new one is built with x64 versions of Apache and PHP, which might be a problem?  And I'm getting the warning to not have extended discussions in comments, so I don't know the protocol here for that. :)

Answer (score 2):

RESOLVED!

I had to enable extension=php_mbstring.dll in php.ini.

Comment: After hours of searching and trying different options, this is the only one that worked for me! (PHP+MYSQL+APACHE on windows 2012 R2). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your intended use is for the server but try XAMPP https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html. Phpmyadmin will work right out of the box!

Comment: It's a local dev environment, and my preference has always been to set it all up manually for 100% control and to "keep my hands dirty". :)

Comment: Sounds like you've got the right idea about how to approach a dev environment, however I would suggest using an actual server OS instead of a desktop environment. Windows 8 can do the trick but your current problem is probably a missing dependency that a server OS would solve right off the bat. It's also a better idea to have a server OS installed so that your dev environment can resemble a production one as closely as possible. Try heading over to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/ to find an affordable approach to this. It's better to have a strong foundation instead of patching a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (totally blank page for phpMyAdmin)

Windows 11 / PHP 8 / IIS-Server 10

Everything was running ok until my php.ini file go corrupted somehow. I recreated my php.ini file from the php.ini-development file. After this PHP was running again without any problems but it had that mentioned plank page for phpMyAdmin

In the IIS-Server Managementpanel there is a tool "PHP Manager". There I used the option "Register new PHP version". This function recreated the needed settings in my php.ini file. Everything was working again after this

What this tool changed in the php.ini was to add the following entries to the very bottom of file:

```
; List of headers files to preload, wildcard patterns allowed.
;ffi.preload=
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
[PHP_GETTEXT]
extension=php_gettext.dll
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
[PHP_MBSTRING]
extension=php_mbstring.dll
[PHP_OPENSSL]
extension=php_openssl.dll
[PHP_SOAP]
extension=php_soap.dll
[PHP_GD]
extension=php_gd.dll
```

Maybe this will help someone too....

Answer (score -1):

Try to turn on your phpmyadmin at your server panel